# Absolute method to find the domain of a composite function

Tags: functions

Let two functions $  h:\mathbb R → \mathbb R , g:\mathbb R → \mathbb R $ be defined by the formulas $ h(x)=\sqrt{x-1} $, $ g(x)=3x^{2}-1 $ with
$ D(h)=\{x \in 
\mathbb R:x≥1\} $

What is the domain of $ g \circ h $ ?

There are two ways to solve this question. One is using the definition of $ D(g \circ h) $ which is,
$D(g \circ h)=\{x \in D(h) : h(x) \in D(g)\} $

Here,$ D(g) = \mathbb R$ . So, $ h(x) \in \mathbb R \ \ \forall x≥1  \implies  D(g \circ h)=\{x \in 
\mathbb R:x≥1\} $

Another way is to get the composite function and then finding the domain manually.
So, we get, $ g \circ h=g(h(x))=g(\sqrt{x-1}) = 3(\sqrt{x-1})^2 -1=3x-4
 $ . It's clear that for all $ x \in \mathbb R \ \,  g \circ h $ holds . So $ D( g \circ h) = \mathbb R $ .

What is correct then?

Comment: The 1st one is correct. Not the 2nd one, because $(\sqrt{x-1})^2$ is equal to $x-1$ only when it is defined, i.e. when $x-1\ge0.$ Btw, "for all $ x \in \mathbb R \ \,  g \circ h $ holds" is meaningless. I think you meant the (however wrong) statement "for all $ x \in \mathbb R \ \,  g \circ h (x)$ is defined.

Answer (score 1):

The second method is not correct.

Consider a simpler example,
$$\begin{align*}
&f : \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} \to \mathbb{R} \\
&g : \mathbb{R}  \to \mathbb{R} \\
&f(x) = \sqrt x\\
&g(x) = x^2
\end{align*}$$
How does one find $g(f(x))$ for a particular $x$, e.g. how does one find $g(f(2))$? Well, you find $f(2)$ first, and plug that into $g(x)$. You do not simplify first. (Remember your discussions on removable discontinuities from Calculus I?)

Hypothetically, say we expanded the domain of $f$ to include, say, $-1$. But then we have $(\sqrt{-1})^2$ as $g(f(-1))$. Interpreting the square root as a function of real numbers, then, this is nonsensical: $\sqrt{-1}$ isn't defined, so how can we square it? We can claim to leverage properties about $i^2=-1$, but we're not dealing with complex numbers and you would have to thoroughly justify the use of exponent properties.

Another framing is that you can only claim $g(f(x)) = x$ for $x$ for which $f(x)$ is defined, and in turn that $g(f(x))$ is defined. At every step along the way you need to ensure that.

Another framing is that, into $g(f(x))$, look at what numbers you plug in to find $f(x)$ first. You have to be able to plug them into $f$ first and foremost, so you're looking at its domain, not a "sensible widening" of the domain as your second method tries to use.

Answer (score 0):

The first method is correct. Not the second one, because $(\sqrt{x-1})^2$
is equal to $x−1$
only when it is defined, i.e. when $x−1≥0.$ Therefore, "$3(\sqrt{x-1})^2 -1=3x-4$" does not hold for every real number $x,$ but only for $x\ge1.$

By the way, "for all $ x \in \mathbb R \ \,  g \circ h $ holds" is meaningless. I think you meant the (however wrong) statement "for all $ x \in \mathbb R \ \,  (g \circ h)(x)$ is defined".

Comment: I just tried to improve this answer, but without any explanation from  the downvoter, it is difficult to know how do do better.